# Battery Issues-Moto E

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery-life, motorola-moto-e

I am facing battery issues from days,the battery does not survive even a day even without using the internet.
Tried uninstalling some apps but there is no effect. It is happening 10 days after 4.4.4 Kitkat update.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: My moto E battery lasts for more than 36 hours. The phone does claim to have very decent battery life and hence, if I were you, I will factory reset the phone and will use without installing apps to see whether the life improves. If it is okay then some app is coded badly. If still facing same problem, then there should be a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use battery monitor in settings to see what's causing the battery drain. Uninstalling apps is not the solution, until you've identified that as the problem.  You can either access your battery stats in settings or in notification shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en) and hibernate all unused apps, this actually stops the apps from running in background. This fixed the problem for me as I am an extensive apps user.

Answer (score -1):

Diagonise apps with any antivirus or security app and see what is the reason for fast draining of battery.usually the apps which use more RAM are the reasons for less backup of battery. Uninstalling those unwanted apps is the solution

Comment: How is this different from [the other answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/78280/16575)? And why should apps using more ***RAM*** be the reason? It's rather apps using more CPU, network, disk i/o, and wake-locks. RAM doesn't consume more battery whether it's used or free.