# MOTO E battery drops suddenly to 0%

Tags: charging, battery-life, motorola-moto-e

My moto E phone is not even a month old, and already I'm having a HUGE problem with it.

I charge my phone to full battery, sometimes during a whole afternoon or night. In the morning or at 100% I unplug the USB. The phone then last a while on battery, but suddenly the battery drops to 0% and the phone shuts down. I can't get the phone back on again unless I plug it in with the USB to charge it.

Then, the battery charges ridiculously fast to 100%, sometimes in just a few minutes. When I check the battery graph, it shows that the phone uses the battery steadely for a while until there is a sudden and steep drop for no reason whatsoever. This drop occurs seemingly randomly sometimes happening at around 90% charge, sometimes 80%, 70%, 60%... There are no special apps running, and the phone is not even connected to the internet, not by WIFI or the phone network.

Why is this happening? I can't leave my house with my new phone without the charger cable, even at 100% battery, because often I end up looking for a computer to charge my phone on after only an hour or two because my phone has shut down!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your battery is faulty. You would have to replace that.You should also check [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78129/battery-issues-moto-e)

Answer (score 2):

OK - This issue is still happening.
I hope, since your phone was new and under warranty, that you took it back to get a new one.

There are people still experiencing this same thing. It is being discussed in the Levono/Motorola forums.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-E-2nd-Gen/Moto-E-2nd-sudden-battery-drain-and-power-off/m-p/3862539#M4467

The solution presented by a Motorola Agent was to plug the phone in to a wall charging unit, let it charge to 100%, and then keep charging it for awhile. This seems to have worked for me. My phone is about 2 years old. So, I can't take it back for an exchange.

But, another user isn't as lucky as me. So, any addition information or solution suggestions would be helpful here or on that other forum.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone (or possibly the battery) is faulty. Return it to the shop for a replacement.